# Embedded windows media player doesn't work on alfresco

Tags: alfresco, windows-media-player, alfresco-share

I wanna use embedded windows media player on our alfresco system for displaying .mkv etc.
I already defined windows media player on alfresco but it doesn't resolve the video url different than internet explorer.  I use as default the url from web-preview.js which is also provide url for the other players.  When I try the use share button and then view button I can watch the videos on each browser.

So, I give up the trying adjust url from web-preview.js. I just wanna take quick share's source url for the video details page.

Is it possible?
This is my super class. It is default never changed:

```
 getContentUrl: function WP_getContentUrl(download)
  {
     var proxy = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + Alfresco.constants.URL_CONTEXT + "proxy/" + this.options.proxy + "/",
        nodeRefAsLink = this.options.nodeRef.replace(":/", ""),
        noCache = "noCache=" + new Date().getTime();
     download = download ? "a=true" : "a=false";
     return proxy + this.options.api + "/node/" + nodeRefAsLink + "/content/" + encodeURIComponent(this.options.name) + "?c=force&" + noCache + "&" + download
  },

  getContentUrl: function WP_getContentUrl(download)
  {
     var proxy = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + Alfresco.constants.URL_CONTEXT + "proxy/" + this.options.proxy + "/",
        nodeRefAsLink = this.options.nodeRef.replace(":/", ""),
        noCache = "noCache=" + new Date().getTime();
     download = download ? "a=true" : "a=false";
     return proxy + this.options.api + "/node/" + nodeRefAsLink + "/content/" + encodeURIComponent(this.options.name) + "?c=force&" + noCache + "&" + download
  },


  getThumbnailUrl: function WP_getThumbnailUrl(thumbnail, fileSuffix)
  {
     var proxy = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + Alfresco.constants.URL_CONTEXT + "proxy/" + this.options.proxy + "/",
        nodeRefAsLink = this.options.nodeRef.replace(":/", ""),
        noCache = "noCache=" + new Date().getTime(),
        force = "c=force";

     // Check to see if last modification data is available for the thumbnail...
     for (var i = 0; i < this.options.thumbnailModification.length; i++)
     {
        if (this.options.thumbnailModification[i].indexOf(thumbnail) != -1)
        {
           noCache = "lastModified=" + encodeURIComponent(this.options.thumbnailModification[i]) + "&" + noCache;
           break;
        }
     }
     return proxy + this.options.api + "/node/" + nodeRefAsLink + "/content/thumbnails/" + thumbnail + (fileSuffix ? "/suffix" + fileSuffix : "") + "?" + force + "&" + noCache
  }
```

and thats the my code's display method which is not work for firefox,chrome,opera etc. :

```
display: function Video_display()
   {
       var src = this.attributes.src ? this.wp.getThumbnailUrl(this.attributes.src) : this.wp.getContentUrl();

        var height=240;   
        var width=320;    
        var player = '<object ';
        player += 'height="' + height.toString() + '" ';
        player += 'width="' + width.toString() + '" ';

        if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("MSIE") < 0) {
            // Chrome, Firefox, Opera, Safari
            player += 'type="application/x-ms-wmp" ';
            player += 'data="' + src + '" >';
        }
        else {
            // Internet Explorer
            player += 'classid="clsid:6BF52A52-394A-11d3-B153-00C04F79FAA6" >';
            player += '<param name="url" value="' + src + '" />';
        }

        player += '<param name="autoStart" value="false" />';
        player += '<param name="playCount" value="1" />';
        player += '</object>';

        return player;
   }
```

Comment: 1. How did you defined WMP on alfresco? 2. What is the URL you get? 3. What URL do you expect?

Comment: 1. http://blogs.alfresco.com/wp/wabson/2012/04/11/share-document-previews-in-alfresco-4/ this is the my guide for defining windows media player on alfresco.simply i created a file which is name MediaPlayer.js as copy of Video.js and then i changed the web-preview.get.head.ftl for dependency then i changed the web-preview.get.config.xml for  
alignment.

Comment: 2-my url something like this "http://10.0.0.84:8080/share/page/site/test-projesi/http%3A%2F%2F10.0.0.84%3A8080%2Fshare%2Fproxy%2Falfresco%2Fapi%2Fnode%2Fworkspace%2FSpacesStore%2F7e74db85-e276-4b2c-90e6-e1de2d3353b0%2Fcontent%2FWildlife.wmv%3Fc%3Dforce%26noCache%3D1378814630014%26a%3Dfalse"  3- i expect this "http://10.0.0.84:8080/share/s/http%3A%2F%2F10.0.0.84%3A8080%2Fshare%2Fproxy%2Falfresco-noauth%2Fapi%2Finternal%2Fshared%2Fnode%2FiL-FMjMOSlKxkBDiT6pkDg%2Fcontent%2FWildlife.wmv%3Fc%3Dforce%26noCache%3D1378815014337%26a%3Dfalse"

Comment: i just need this code : iL-FMjMOSlKxkBDiT6pkDg which is name shareId but i don't know how can i invoke this value on my mediaPlayer.js

Comment: Can you share your code?